# How to find an element?

Tags: java, servlets, set

How I can check if the element in a set is existing?

```
public class Account
{
    public Account(String username, String password, String lastname, String firstname){
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }


    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        boolean result = false;
        if (obj != null && obj instanceof Account)
        {
            Account p = (Account)obj;
            if ( getUsername().equals(p.getUsername()) 
              && getPassword() == p.getPassword() )
            {
                result = true;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**My Servlet**

```
Set<Account> acc = new HashSet<Account>();

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        acc.add(new Account("test1", "pass123", "Boom", "Bang"));
            acc.add(new Account("test2", "pass123", "Beam", "Beng"));
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String username = "";
        String password = "";


    if(request.getParameter("Username") != null){
        username = request.getParameter("Username");
    }
    if(request.getParameter("Password") != null){
        password = request.getParameter("Password");
    }

    Account act1 = new Account(username, password, "", "","");

            /*
            Works only on hard code
            Account act1 = new Account("test1", "pass123", "", "","");
            */

        out.print("<html>");
        out.print("<head><link href='layoutit/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>"
                + "<link href='layoutit/css/style.css' rel='stylesheet'>");
        out.print("<title></title>");
        out.print("</head>");
        out.print("<body");
        for (Account p : acc)
        {
            if(p.equals(act1){

                out.print("<h3>Click <a href='displayuser.html'>here</a> to continue.</h3>");
            }
            else{
                out.print("<h1>Invalid user account entered.Click <a href='index.html'>here</a> to login.</h1>");
            }
        }
        out.print("</body>");
        out.print("</hmtl>");
        out.close();
    }
```

Comment: Read the Javadoc of `HashSet`.

Answer (score 1):

Set has a 'contains' method as well as any type extending/implementing Collection. You have to be careful on implementing equals and hashcode for your Account type. You can find the details on the [Object type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Override the `equals(Object)` (with a proper implementation) in your `Account` class and then do:

```
boolean containsAccount = acc.contains(some_account)
```

where `some_account` is an `instanceof` `Account`

Comment: I will do the containsAccount in my servlet?

Comment: @KarlxSwanovski Correct